# j_spring_security_check is not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I upgraded Spring Security from 2 to 3

Previously Security.xml has **AuthenticationProcessingFilter** and  **AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint**

So my new Security.xml is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">
<beans:bean id="userAuthenticationService"
    class="com.raykor.core.service.UserAuthenticationService" />

<beans:bean id="shaEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

<global-method-security />

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

    <intercept-url pattern="/resettingPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthenticationService">
        <password-encoder ref="shaEncoder">
            <salt-source user-property="salt" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="authenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
        ref="failureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="successHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home.do" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="failureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.do?error=true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.do" />
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

`

Also added filter **springSecurityFilterChain** in web.xml

On login.do it opens Login Page,On Submit it submits to **j_spring_security_check** with username and password as **j_username** & **j_password**

So why is it saying as j_spring_security_checknot avaliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed to add custom-filter ref i updated 
as

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resettingPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>
```

Comment: You define here a custom filter, however it would be enough to include a `<form-login>` element and set its attributes, which would create the same `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as your "custom" filter.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, but it won't be part of the security filter chain just by creating it. Try removing the `auto-config="false"` from the `http` config element, and include a `<form-login>` element within that. I think all the configuration that you have done through the bean definitions can be done using the more concise [namespace configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic) which should be preferred with Spring Security 3.

Comment: I have also added **LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint** so i kept auto-config="false". Anyways thanks for response I got solution and also answered my own Question

Comment: You don't need to switch off auto-config just for setting a custom entry point (although you might want to do that for some other reasons), using the `entry-point-ref` attribute is enough.

Comment: Don't use `auto-config` at all. It just confuses people and is better removed from your configuration completely (pretend it doesn't exist). Add the `<form-login>` element explicitly as described.